# c language printing out value in pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am trying to print out values in integer pointer. This pointer stores binary search tree keys inorder way.

So my inorder function is,

```
int traversal(int* num,node *t, int i) {

    if (t == NULL) {
        return i;
    }
    if (t->left != NULL) {
        i = traversal(num, t->left, i);
    }
    num[i] = &(t->value);
    i++;
    if (t->right != NULL) {
        i = traversal(num, t->right, i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

And print function is,

```
void traversalPrint(int* nums) {
    for (int i = 0; nums[i] !='\0'; i++) {
        printf("%d", &nums[i]); 
    }

}

int main(){
    int* numPtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(int*));
    node* bst = NULL:
    traversal(numPtr, bst, 0);
    traversalPrint(numPtr);
}
```

My issue is `traversalPrint` function prints out `numPtr`'s memory address, not value. 
How can I print out pointer's value?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `&` in `&nums[i]` gives you back the memory address. It's only needed for strings.

Comment: @0decimal0 any reason you don't vote to close as duplicate and just put a comment?

Comment: @bolov My privileges I guess.

Comment: @0decimal0 what does that mean?

Comment: @bolov Close voting access begins at 5k rep.

Comment: didn't know that

Comment: @bolov You get it now , sir :P

Comment: @MateenUlhaq what do you mean by "it's only needed for strings? `&nums[i]` gives you the address of the array element of any type. The only qualification of a C string is that the `char` array ends with a `nul` terminator.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Yeah there isn't even any `char` type here.

Comment: With warnings turned on: *warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]*

Answer (score 1):

The issue concerning "printing addresses" is that with `printf("%d", &nums[i])`, you actually take the address of "something". Note that `&anObject` gives you the memory address of `anObject`, and `&nums[i]` gives the memory address of `nums[i]` (which is the address of the i'th element of `nums`). BTW: `%d` is the wrong format specifier for pointer values, and you actually yield undefined behaviour by doing so.

For printing the integral value, use `printf("%d", nums[i])` instead.

Note further that the code in your main function does not allocate anything for `nums`, such that your program will write to non-initialized memory and will again yield undefined behaviour.

use at least `int* numPtr = calloc(MAXNODES, sizeof(int))` instead, thereby making sure that every entry is initialized with `0`. Otherwise, your comparison in `nums[i] !='\0'` (which, BTW, should be written as `nums[i] != 0`) will probably fail, again leading to UB later on.

Comment: I edited `numPtr` as `numPtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(int));` and tried. but does not have any luck. Then I changed it as you described `numPtr=calloc(sizeof(node*), sizeof(int));` but not luck as well. Is `MAXNODES` same as sizeof(node*) or do you mean something different?

Answer (score 0):

Try `nums[i]` instead of `&nums[i]`.